# Is it possible to get the value of ui:field

Tags: gwt, widget, uibinder

I have a use case where I need to get the widget name. In my uibinder I have this widget

```
<g:Label ui:field="label1" ></g:Label>
```

After somewhere else in the code I want to get the value of `ui:field` from `Widget` object

```
Widget w = getWidgetFromSomewhereNotImportant();
//TODO get the widget name
```

Any idea ?

Comment: It's not possible; so the question is: why do you need it? wouldn't there be another way to solve your problem?

Comment: I want to set ids on the widgets dynamically for testing purpose. I was looking for a unique and permanent ids by page. I thought the widget's name could be a good idea but I see that it's impossible. Is there any other alternatives ?

Comment: `debugId`? http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure i understand your problem here , but you can create a method in the view you are using your widget in , like 
    public Widget getMyWidget() {
      return this.myWidget;//myWidget is the widget you want
    }

and you can call it each time u want to get a reference to your widget maybe using a presenter if you are too far.

Comment: Calling the widget from the view is not the issue.